# TV remote control layout with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to design a TV remote control using flexbox (I would use Grid but it is not supported by webkit).

I'm struggling to align/center the items around the "OK" item.

I was thinking to create an "invisible" item but I can't find any such thing on the flexbox specs (empty space seems to be ignored).

I feel that defining "margins" is not exactly the right way to do this.

It should look as below

```
         Up
         |
<left----OK---Right-->
         |
        Down
```

But it looks like more like this

```
             Up
             |
<left----OK---Right-->
             |
             Down
```

Here you can [play it](https://jsfiddle.net/sbfnt5aa/1/).

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.up {
  order: 1;
  margin-left: 40%;
  margin-right: 50%;
}

.left {
  order: 2;
  margin-left: 30%;
}

.ok {
  order: 3;
}

.right {
  order: 4;
  margin-right: 40%;
}

.down {
  order: 5;
  margin-left: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <form action="/keyboard/" class="up">
    <input type="hidden" name="q" value="126" />
    <button type submit class="button-large">Up </button>
  </form>
  <form action="/keyboard/" class="left">
    <input type="hidden" name="q" value="123" />
    <button type submit class="button-large">Left</button>
  </form>
  <form action="/keyboard/" class="ok">
    <input type="hidden" name="q" value="36" />
    <button type submit class="button-large">OK</button>
  </form>
  <form action="/keyboard/" class="right">
    <input type="hidden" name="q" value="124" />
    <button type submit class="button-large">Right</button>
  </form>
  <form action="/keyboard/" class="down">
    <input type="hidden" name="q" value="125" />
    <button type submit class="button-large">Down;</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually not too complicated. Just need some adjustments to your CSS. No changes necessary to your HTML.

```css
.grid {
  display: inline-flex;           /* 1 */
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.up, .down {
  flex: 0 0 100%;                 /* 2 */
  text-align: center;             /* 2 */
}

.left, .right {
  flex: 1 0 1%;                   /* 3 */
  display: flex;
}

.left  { justify-content: flex-end; }
.right { justify-content: flex-start; }

.ok {}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <form action="/keyboard/" class="up">
    <input type="hidden" name="q" value="126" />
    <button type submit class="button-large">Up </button>
  </form>
  <form action="/keyboard/" class="left">
    <input type="hidden" name="q" value="123" />
    <button type submit class="button-large">Left</button>
  </form>
  <form action="/keyboard/" class="ok">
    <input type="hidden" name="q" value="36" />
    <button type submit class="button-large">OK</button>
  </form>
  <form action="/keyboard/" class="right">
    <input type="hidden" name="q" value="124" />
    <button type submit class="button-large">Right</button>
  </form>
  <form action="/keyboard/" class="down">
    <input type="hidden" name="q" value="125" />
    <button type submit class="button-large">Down</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sbfnt5aa/5/)

Notes:

1. Size container to content size (not `width: 100%`).
2. Occupy all space in the row, then center inline content.
3. Consume all free space in the row (does not apply to "OK", which takes content width only). The `flex-basis: 1%` is solely for Safari, which doesn't otherwise break `.left` to the second row as it should.

Comment: any idea why it looks broken on webkit?

Comment: In testing the layout in Safari, I now see what you're talking about. `flex: 0 0 100%` on the first row (`.up`) *is not* forcing subsequent items (starting with `.left`) to the second row. It should, because there should be no space available for another element. I guess it's a bug. To force this to happen, I added a `flex-basis: 1%` to `.left` and `.right`. @vals